# My cats are throwing up right after eating

Tags: cats

I have multiple cats that throw up right after eating. I have tried changing the bowls to slow feed bowls. I have tried to modify their food slightly (same food they have always had before incident started). I don't know what else to do. Nothing is wrong health wise with them, healthy kittios :)

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! When did the cats last seen the vet? How do you know, they are healthy?

Comment: I just took them to the vet for their yearly.

Comment: What did the vet said about the vomitting?

Comment: They told me to use the slow feed bowl but they still vomit. It's random times too...not always

Comment: I assume you feed dry food... If you put one piece of food into a bowl of water, how much and how quickly does it expand? Dry foods with a high grain contend can cause vomiting because they expand inside the stomach within a few minutes. Foods with low grain content shouldn't expand much at all or do so very slowly.

Comment: I used purina pro plan. I've been feeding this to my cats for years. Never had a prob til this last year.

Comment: Sometimes cats develop sensitivities to certain proteins in dry foods over time, I'd discuss this possibility with your vet, they usually have samples of hypoallergenic dry foods ready you can try if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not just dry foods; protein allergies can apply to dry foods too. Look at which kind of meat is used in the current food and see if the cat will eat a food based on something else; if they may be reacting to chicken, which is the most common cat food meat in the US,  I'd try turkey, beef, or maybe fish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!